# Sharpen a blue cheese dressing?

Tags: cheese

My penecillium rocqueforti ripened blue nutcheese still hasn't sharpened in flavor ie ketone development which takes 6mo or more.
Otherwise flavor and aroma fine at this point.

Would like to use in dressing.
Adding bit of sharpness to mix desireable.

Sodium citrate suggesting in this post: [How does kraft mac and cheese or velveeta get that tangy flavor?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/115909/how-does-kraft-mac-and-cheese-or-velveeta-get-that-tangy-flavor)

Any other suggestion for rocquefort-like tang?

Comment: FWIW, absolutely *not* sodium citrate. Different sort of tang. I'm afraid the answer is likely "several more months".

Comment: Will try prickly ash oil ie sichuan pepper for added burn.  Wish there was a source of these flavorsome blue ketones. Perilla leaves do have some but are heavier in sassafras flavor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per old chef acquaintance:
dry mustard and white pepper.

I also added a couple drops prickly ash oil (sichuan pepper)

And that perked things up immensely.

Comment: I'm not sure of the background, but mustard powder definitely acts as a sort of flavour enhancer for cheese.  I haven't tried it on blue cheese though and it might be better at bringing out the cheese flavour than the blueness

Comment: I do have plenty of blue flavor in cheese but not tangy-sharp, think cambozola mild. Some blue cheese dressing recipes out there have mustard powder (english best) and black pepper so it didn't taste odd at all.